# Given certain elements of a proper subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, determine $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Question:** Suppose that $H$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition and that $H$ contains $18$, $30$, and $40$. Determine $H$.

Can we determine $H$ without knowing the order of $\mathbb{Z}$? Please don't tell the answer; I just need a hint.

Comment: I am slightly confused by the first sentence in the second paragraph. We already know the order the $\mathbb{Z}$ (it is infinite). Do you perhaps mean the index of $H$ in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The wording of the question isn't very good.  We can't actually determine $H$ just by knowing that it contains certain elements.  I presume what is meant is that $H$ contains only those elements and the elements that it has to contain as a consequence of containing those ones (i.e. those elements generate $H$), but it should say that.

Comment: @TaraB: In this question, $H$ is a proper subgroup containing the element $2$, and so it can be determined. But in general, yes, you are right.

Comment: @user1729:  Ah, you are right.  I had missed that the word 'proper' gives the necessary extra information.

Answer (score 3):

If $H\leq\mathbb Z$ so for some $n\neq 1,0$,  $~~H=n\mathbb Z$ (Any proper subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ should be of this form). 
Now think of this: $$18=nk,~ 30=nk',~ 40=nk'',~~ k,k',k''\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: what does $H=nZ$ means???Order of $Z$ is divisible by order of $H$

Comment: $n\mathbb{Z}$ is shorthand for the set $\{nk; k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, which is the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the element $n$ (why?). Note that all subgroups of a cyclic group are themselves cyclic, so $H=n\mathbb{Z}=\langle n\rangle$ for some $1\neq n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\ddot\smile{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint $1$: The greatest common devisor of $18$, $30$ and $40$ is which number and why is this relevant?

Hint $2$: To find $H$, think about what happens if $\operatorname{gcd}(18, 30, 40)$ is prime and if it is composite.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was not on here to help the OP. +1

Comment: @ResidentDementor How does it matter whether gcd is prime or composite though? Just that there could be multiple proper subgroups in case gcd is composite?

Comment: @yathish Yes, exactly. There may be multiple proper subgroups, so $H$ cannot be determined. (I consider the word "determined" to mean "determined uniquely", like in a deterministic automata. I think this definition is standard.)

Answer (score 1):

As an example of the sort of reasoning you might use, you might think that since $18 \in H$ and $30\in H$, we know that $18 + 18 - 30 = 6 \in H$. Using reasoning like this, you can arrive at a unique answer.